# XSLT - number formatting

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a number of tags similar to below -

```
<head>
<data>0.00</data>
<anotherdata>0.00</anotherdata>
</head>
```

Is there a way to convert all these to 0 and 0 using XSLT? The tags that I provided are examples and there are a number of tags that have similar data with decimal values.

Comment: What kind of code is `>0.00< >0.0<`? If your input is XML, please show a well-formed XML as the input example - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your input looks like, but certainly:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number('0.00')" />
```

returns:

```
0
```

Comment: @michael.ho257k , is there a way to convert 109.90 to 109.9? I would like to remove the trailing 0.

Comment: @PunterVicky Same thing: `number('109.90')` returns `109.9`.